# Constraint Layout is taking full width when a child is wrap_content in height

Tags: android-view, android-constraintlayout, viewgroup, android-wrap-content

I want the test view to take only as much height as occupied by the rest of the card. (See images at the end of code snippet) But it is pushing the height of the view to the entire screen.

It works as we want only after supplying 0 height, which doesn't seem right.
What can be done apart from providing **0 height** to achieve this behavior?

````
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"

            android:text="Dialog title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/test"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>```


 what I want   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NU4d.png
 what shows up [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6qEn.png
````

Comment: Share your layout which you want to design.

Comment: @MehulKabaria
 what I want   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NU4d.png
 what shows up [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6qEn.png

Comment: I have post answer check it

Comment: @MehulKabaria, thanks for the answer,r possible to do this without 0 dp, ?
Have mentioned the same in my question too

Comment: can i know what is reason to do it without 0dp??

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to change the bottom constraint for your `View` and make the height of the `View` a 0dp.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/echo">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"

            android:text="Dialog title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/test"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output :

[image]